# Need BIG DATA SETS FOR Multiple Linear Regression computing

Tags: dataset, bigdata, linear-regression

I need BIG DATA SETS FOR Multiple Linear Regression computing for experimentation thesis please ( up to 3 million example)

Comment: Have you checked this one? http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public

Answer (score 1):

You can find huge datasets for Regression in research journals. There are none available on the internet of the above mentioned size. You can create a data of your own by taking imaginary variables and do analysis on it ;)